# Matrix Transpose in C

Tags: c, matrix, transpose, matrix-transform

Suppose I define a matrix and assign the value in the following way:

```
 double A[row * column];

 for (int j = 0; j < column; j++){
     for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
       A[j*row + i] = ((double)rand())/RAND_MAX; // random value
     }
   }
```

How can I compute the transpose of this matrix? I have tried the following but the resulting matrix is not correct.

```
double B[column * row]; 

for(int j = 0; j < row; j++){
     for(int i = 0; i < column; i++){
       B[j*row + i] = A[i*row + j];
     }
   }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'it did not work'? Is there an error message?

Comment: It did not generate the correct matrix @Codor

Comment: Show snippet to generate output, actual output and expected output.

Comment: Transposing a matrix is similar to swapping the values of two variables. think about that simple case and what could go wrong there. Then check your code for the complicated way of making the same mistake.

Comment: Unless `column == row`, you need to use different multipliers when copying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The indexing should be done in the following way.

```
double B[column * row];

for (int j = 0; j < row; j++){
    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++){
        B[j*column + i] = A[i*row + j];
    }
}
```